# Handle DataTable.DataRow cell change event

Tags: winforms, datatable, datarow, datacolumn

I have a DataTable that has several DataColumns and DataRow. Now i would like to handle an event when cell of this DataRow is changed. How to do this in c#?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks as though the DataTable.ColumnChanged event will do what you want

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.columnchanged.aspx